# Need some suggestions to adding new tabs using JQuery ui Tabs!

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I am going to use [JQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) Plugin on my web application.

And now I need some suggestions to resolve problems.

**First,** I want to the new added tab to be selected when new tab and its contents had been created. E.g. When I click to make a new tab ,the new tab and its contents should be display as soon as possible.

**Second,** I need a button beside tab-list [ **should be the last tab** ] to create a **new blank tab and contents**.Just link **firefox or chrome's tab style**.So,I can let the user to load the new contents by himself.

Thank you very much for any kind of suggestions !!

[UPDATE]
To switch the new created Tab.There is a plugin option to do it:

**[selected](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#default):**

```
Zero-based index of the tab to be selected on initialization. To set all tabs to unselected pass -1 as value.
```

Code examples

```
Initialize a tabs with the selected option specified.
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ selected: 3 });
Get or set the selected option, after init.
//getter
var selected = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

when u create a new tab add the class `.ui-tabs-selected` to the newly created tab... u can use $`("#idOfNewlyCreatedTab").addClass(".ui-tabs-selected")` and make sure to remove this class from the previously currently selected tab...

Comment: Thanks. But in this way I had to do lots of addClass() and removeClass(). I'll try it later .

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a global variable like "tabCounter" that is incremented and decremented as tabs are added or removed.

To add a new tab, set its URL, and then switch to the newly added tab, you can do this:

```
function addTab(tabTitle, url) {
   // Add the tab
   $tabs.tabs("add", "#tabs-" + tabCounter, tabTitle);

   // Set the url of the new tab
   $tabs.tabs("url", tabCounter, url);

   // Switch to the tab.
   $tabs.tabs("select", tabCounter);

   // Increment the tab counter.
   tabCounter++;
}
```